# SELECT CONCAT alternative in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, concatenation

How can I write the following MySQL query in PostgreSQL syntax:

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", (COUNT(parent.name) - 1)), cat.name) AS name
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use concatenation signs ||

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error here is that PostgreSQL doesn't allow double quotes `"` for literal strings (as per the SQL standard). You'll need to use single quotes `'`.

You also need to cast `(COUNT(parent.name) - 1)` to an integer, either using `::int` (specific to Postgre) or `CAST(... AS int)`.
Note that this may raise an `integer out of range` error if `(COUNT(parent.name) - 1)` is superior to 2147483647.

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', (COUNT(parent.name) - 1)::int), cat.name) AS name
```

Note that you can also use `||` for string concatenation :

```
SELECT REPEAT('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', (COUNT(parent.name) - 1)::int) || cat.name AS name
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, but I have another issue: it throws me an error: function repeat(unknown, bigint) does not exist.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. The error says: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. I tried to add CAST to the function arguments, but the error remains.

Comment: @ГеоргиБанков : updated my answer, you need to cast to int (you can see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) that `REPEAT` takes 2 arguments : a string and an integer (not a bigint)).

Comment: Ahh, I tried casting to numeric, instead of int and that was causing the error. Still pretty new new to PostgreSQL. Thanks and +1

Comment: plus 1 for casting to int

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT REPEAT("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", (COUNT(parent.name) - 1)) || cat.name AS name
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3a5f/2)